# How to iterate only last the element of list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3,[0, 1, 2]]
```

I need to print only **[0, 1, 2]** with *for*. So my code is:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for k in range(len(a[i])):
        print(a[i][k])
```

but, it`s not working! So, can you help me?

Comment: what's the issue with `print(nums[-1])` ?

Comment: Why do you need a `for`? `print(nums[-1])` would just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No iteration is necessary. You can just access the last element of the list.

The naive way of doing this is finding the index of the last element, which is the length - 1.

```
print(nums[len(nums)-1])
```

Fortunately in Python you can access things at index from the end, using negative indexes, so you can just write

```
print(nums[-1])
```

---

To iterate over that you can use it as the subject of the for loop:

```
for num in nums[-1]:
    print(f'{num} {num*num}')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how can i do this with iteration, it`s possible? I mean, how to iterate over a nested array?

Comment: I've edited with a loop over just that list. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thx!!))))))))))

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do it iterating. But if you want to iterate do it that way.

```
nums = [1, 2, 3,[0, 1, 2]] 
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if i == len(nums)-1:
        print(nums[i])
```